# Qual é a finalidade de __slots__?

Tags: python, classes, métodos-mágicos

Para que serve essa propriedade `__slots__`?

Li [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) alguma coisa a respeito de "desperdício de espaço", porém no final das contas não entendi muito bem o propósito de usar `__slots__`.

Pra que ele serve e quando eu deveria usá-lo?

Comment: Essa é a minha pergunta 700 aqui no site :p

Comment: 722 c/ as deletadas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O `__slots__` é um atributo bem especial para classes - quando ele não está presente, para cada nova instância da classe, o Python cria um novo dicionário, mas ele não faz isso se a classe definir `__slots__`.

Isso é, vamos supor que eu queira uma classe "Ponto" só para guardar um par de coordenadas (e posso adicionar métodos - mas não muda nada aqui).

Em Python posso escrever (Python 3 - em Python 2 é necessário herdar de `object`):

```
class Ponto:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
    ...
```

E isso é o que conhecemos normalmente. Podemos, depois de instanciar um ponto, acrescentar um atributo `z` a ele:

```
p = Ponto()
p.z = 0
```

Sabemos que, via de regra,  não é boa prática, mas a linguagem aceita - e a ideia de *"adultos que consentem"* do Python é que evita código ruim que acrescenta atributos ao acaso à objetos de classes já existentes.

Agora - na maioria das vezes você *não* precisa adicionar novos atributos aos seus pontos. E - como cada instância de Ponto tem um dicionário para armazenar seus atributos, acontece que uma instância que só usaria um pouco mais que o espaço necessário a dois objetos do tipo `float` para - talvez uns ~80 bytes no total, passa a precisar também de um dicionário Python inteiro, ainda que zerado - isso tem mais de 200 bytes.

Quando a classe define `__slots__` o Python reserva direto espaço para os atributos definidos em  `__slots__` na estrutura da classe, e **não** cria um novo dicionário para cada instância.

Ou seja, esta:

```
class Ponto:
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
```

terá a mesma funcionalidade que a outra, mas um tamanho de cerca de 80 bytes, e não ~300.

Por outro lado, tentar criar um novo atributo resulta no erro:

> AttributeError: 'Ponto' object has no attribute 'z'

Em sistemas grandes que vão ter milhares de objetos pequenos, isso pode realmente fazer uma diferença. Também se pode imaginar outras formas de tirar proveito desse mecanismo - por exemplo: o Python cria os atributos de classe automaticamente (`dir(Ponto)` na classe acima vai mostrar os atributos x e y), etc...

É interessante notar que as classes "builtin" do Python como `object`, `int`, `list`, etc... tem `__slots__` definido - por isso não se pode criar novos atributos em instâncias desse tipo - mas se você herdar qualquer tipo desses, mesmo que deixe o corpo da classe em branco, pode criar novos atributos.

```
namespace = object()
namespace.x = 5
```

(Atribute Error)

```
class NS(object): pass
namespace = NS()
namespace.x = 5
```

(ok)

E também é importante ter em mente de que se você vai criar uma hierarquia de classes e usar `__slots__`, cada subclasse terá que definir `__slots__` também, senão, por padrão, o Python cria o  `__dict__` para a classe.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu tinha visto a resposta no SOEN e ainda na documentação, e não tinha entendido tão bem como na sua explicação +1