# Como bloqueio o acesso a criação de parametros numa classe?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x, encapsulamento

```
import math

class Circulo():

    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.__raio = None

    def get_perimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.raio

    def get_area(self):
        return math.pi * self.raio ** 2

    @property
    def raio(self):
        return self.__raio

    @raio.setter
    def raio(self, x):
        self.__raio = x
```

Tenho a classe acima e desejo encapsular o acesso, de forma que não seja possível atributos dinâmicos na instancia.

ex:

```
c = Circulo()
c.raio = 2 # ok
c.lado = 2 # AttributeError
```

Tentei bloquear os atributos dinâmicos com `getattr` e `setattr`, mas não tive sucesso.

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item in self.__dict__:
        return self.__dict__[item]
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Paramentro ou atributo "%s" inexistente.' % item)

def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key in self.__dict__:
        self.__dict__[key] = value
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Paramentro ou atributo "%s" inexistente.' % key)
```

Answer (score 5):

Tente isto:

```
import math
 
class Circulo():
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.__raio = None
 
    def get_perimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.raio
 
    def get_area(self):
        return math.pi * self.raio ** 2
 
    @property
    def raio(self):
        return self.__raio
 
    @raio.setter
    def raio(self, x):
        self.__raio = x
 
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            raise TypeError("Não pode criar atributos para esta classe")
        object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
 
c = Circulo()
c.raio = 2 # ok
c.lado = 2 # AttributeError
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/8DJxAp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ldlqcwbm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/FreezeClass.py).

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não cai na exeção:

AttributeError: Paramentro ou atributo "_Circulo__raio" inexistente.

Comment: @britodfbr pra mim funciona: http://ideone.com/cbZdJh

Comment: Sim, mas o erro foi acusado em <c.raio>. E deverá ser acusado somente em <c.lado>.

Fiz um fork de teu código em http://ideone.com/BClC2X, acrescentei somente o key para apresentar onde o erro ocorre.

Comment: Talvez utilizar `__slots__` seja mais adequado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221432/5878

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss bem possível.

Answer (score 5):

O que você deseja fazer é claramente função de `__slots__`, vide [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> *Without a `__dict__` variable, instances cannot be assigned new variables not listed in the `__slots__` definition. Attempts to assign to an unlisted variable name raises `AttributeError`.*

Ou seja, se você deseja que apenas o atributo `__raio` exista, basta colocar na classe:

```
__slots__ = ("__raio")
```

Veja o exemplo:

```
import math

class Circulo():

    __slots__ = ("__raio")

    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.__raio = None

    def get_perimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.raio

    def get_area(self):
        return math.pi * self.raio ** 2

    @property
    def raio(self):
        return self.__raio

    @raio.setter
    def raio(self, x):
        self.__raio = x

c = Circulo()
c.raio = 2 # ok
c.lado = 2 # AttributeError
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Z52Ukv).

O resultado será:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 27, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Circulo' object has no attribute 'lado'
```

Lembrando que como `__raio` pertence a lista definida em `__slots__`, a exceção não é disparada no inicializador da classe ao definir o atributo de instância `self.__raio = None`. Não definindo a lista corretamente, uma exceção pode ser disparada dentro da própria classe.

Comment: Relacionada a resposta: [Qual é a finalidade de `__slots__`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176757/5878)

Comment: Valeu @Anderson Carlos Woss, Muito obrigado!!!

Vou estudar este __slots__ agora!! ;D

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, + uma duvida.
O @property se torna desnecessário?

Comment: Aí é você que tem que dizer. Como seu *get/set* só retornam e atribuem o valor, sem nenhuma regra de negócio, sim, ele é desnecessário. Você pode utilizar apenas o atributo como "público".

Comment: Valeu Anderson. Muito obrigado.
Ampliei meus conhecimentos com tua ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

O final com ajuda de Anderson Woss, ficou assim:

```
import math

class FormaGeometrica:
    __slots__ = ()
    def get_area(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(NotImplemented)
    def get_perimetro(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(NotImplemented)


class Circulo(FormaGeometrica):
    __slots__ = ("raio")

    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.raio = None

    def get_perimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.raio

    def get_area(self):
        return math.pi * self.raio ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Circulo()
    c.raio = 2  # ok
    c.get_area()
    c.get_perimetro()
    c.lado = 2  # AttributeError
```

Anteriormente, para conseguir implementar a classe restringindo a criação dinamica de atributos e metodos, tive que reescrever o **setattr**, **getattr** e controlar o **dict** da classe.

A solução final ficou como o código abaixo. **Se alguém tive sugestões para melhoria, serão bem vindas**.

```
from incolumepy.geometria.figura_geometrica import FiguraGeometrica
import math


class Circulo(FiguraGeometrica):
    '''
    >>> c = Circulo()
    >>> c.raio = 1
    >>> c.raio
    1
    >>> c.lado = 2
    Paramentro ou atributo "lado" inexistente.
    '''
    __dict__ = {'raio': None}

    def get_perimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.raio

    def get_area(self):
        return math.pi * self.raio ** 2

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError('Paramentro ou atributo "%s" inexistente.' % item)
        return self.__dict__[item]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError('Paramentro ou atributo "{}" inexistente.'.format(key))
        self.__dict__[key] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Neste caso você desistiu de utilizar a propriedade?

Comment: Foi o que havia conseguido fazer. Não conhecia o __slots__.