# Há alguma diferença entre uma tupla e um objeto com os mesmos tipos de elementos numa lista?

Tags: python, classes, memória, tupla

Preciso operar com muitos pontos e fiquei em dúvida se ao usar um objeto, no lugar de uma `tuple`, para representar cada ponto irá aumentar o consumo de memória.

`metodo1()` é um método genérico para fazer algum tipo de operação com os pontos.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    def metodo1(self):
        self.x = int(self.x/2)
        self.y = int(self.y/3)

p1 = [Point(i+1, i-1) for i in range(10)]
p2 = [(i+1, i-1) for i in range(10)]
```

Para esse exemplo, qual seria a melhor usar (a tupla ou a classe) em termo de performance, caso fosse fazer os mesmos tipos de operações com a lista depois?

```
for i in range(10):
    p1[i].metodo1()
    p2[i] = (int(p2[i][0]/2), int(p2[i][1]/3))

print(p1)
print(p2)
```

Comment: Dentro do seu `for` qual versão você preferiu? A do `p1` ou a do `p2`?

Comment: Prefiro a do p1, deixa tudo mais bem definido

Comment: mas como vou ter que ficar fazendo operações constantemente com os valores, então qualquer ganho ja seria muito bom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim - por padrão, apesar de uma instância de uma classe só consumir de memória os dados de cada instância, e os dados compartilhados com a classe (como o `metodo1`, nesse caso), são compartilhados entre todas as instâncias, por padrão, uma classe em Python vai ter um espaço de nomes (namespace) que é representado internamente por um dicionário: ele aparece como o atributo `__dict__` na instância - e só ele consome quase 200 bytes.

Mas a linguagem resolve isso com um mecanismo que permite desligar o namespace dinâmico, reservando apenas espaço para atributos pré-definidos.São os "slots": na criação de uma classe sem o uso de `dataclass`, deve-se declarar o atributo `__slots__` na classe, como em `__slots__ = ("x", "y")` : isso evita a criação do dicionário e de uma estrutura de dados usado para refereências fracas (`__weakref__`) e uma instância da classe fica equiparável, em consumo de memória, a uma tupla com a mesma quantidade de atributos.

O [decorator `dataclass` implementa, a partir da versão 3.10 do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass), o parâmetro `slots=True` que faz a mesma coisa:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
...

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    def metodo1(self):
        self.x = int(self.x/2)
        self.y = int(self.y/3)
```

(para versões anteriores, é só declarar o atributo `__slots__ = ("x", "y")` no corpo da classe, mesmo para uma dataclass)

Comment: Não seria bom ligar essa pergunta a sua resposta: [Qual é a finalidade de __slots__?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176757/137387)

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia sobre essa função do `__slots__` para evitar o desperdício. A outra resposta completamenta bastante sobre a minha duvida. Então vou poder continuar usando a classe dessa forma